# Should 'is' be added?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"With the utilization of very few resources, the problem is solved aptly and **is** demonstrated by simulation results"
I doubt if 'is' should be written or not.

Comment: No, once is enough.

Comment: I doubt that "is" should be written again.  Or--I wonder whether "is" should be written again.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the 'is' is optional, but, for me, it is better not to repeat the same word twice, because not only will it be better aesthetically, but also it will sound better when you hear it.
So, you should write "With the utilization of very few resources, the problem is solved aptly and demonstrated by simulation results"

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with repeating the same word twice. You do it in your answer—by your logic, shouldn't you have said *not only will it be better aesthetically, but also sound better when you hear it*?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might want repeat the *is*. This keeps the sentence from being ambiguous.

If you just say

> the problem is solved aptly and demonstrated by simulation results

the reader can't tell whether the problem was solved aptly by the simulation results, or whether it the simulation results just demonstrated the solution.

If you say

> the problem is solved aptly and is demonstrated by simulation results,

the second *is* makes it clearer that the phrase *by simulation results* only applies to the verb *demonstrated*.

Actually, there is no reason to try to avoid grammatical ambiguity when only one of the possibilities makes sense, so there is no actual ambiguity. Everybody says

> ... was buried and eaten by worms,

and not

> ... was buried and was eaten by worms,

because it's quite clear that worms don't bury people. I suspect this if you know the subject matter, your sentence isn't actually ambiguous, so there's nothing wrong with leaving out the *is*.